# Skyline of 2D points-Divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, points, divide

I'm working on a project where I have to find the skyline of the points that are not dominated by any other point in the set. A point A(x1,y1) dominates point B(x2,y2) if x1<=x2 && y1<=y2. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxZqq.jpg)

This is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Point> findSkyline(ArrayList<Point> pointsList){
    if (pointsList.size()<=1){
        return pointsList;
    }

    ArrayList<Point> leftSkylinePoints=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Point> rightSkylinePoints=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Point> leftPoints=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Point> rightPoints=new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0;i<pointsList.size()/2;i++){
        leftPoints.add(pointsList.get(i));
    }
    for (int i=pointsList.size()/2;i<pointsList.size();i++){
        rightPoints.add(pointsList.get(i));
    }

    leftSkylinePoints=findSkyline(leftPoints);
    rightSkylinePoints=findSkyline(rightPoints);

    int minY=1001;
    for (int i=0;i<leftSkylinePoints.size();i++){
        if (leftSkylinePoints.get(i).y<minY){
            minY=leftSkylinePoints.get(i).y;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<rightSkylinePoints.size();i++){
        if (rightSkylinePoints.get(i).y>=minY){
            rightSkylinePoints.remove(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("MINY: "+minY);

    System.out.print("Left: ");
    for (int i=0;i<leftSkylinePoints.size();i++){
        System.out.print("("+leftSkylinePoints.get(i).x+","+leftSkylinePoints.get(i).y+") ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Right: ");
    for (int i=0;i<rightSkylinePoints.size();i++){
        System.out.print("("+rightSkylinePoints.get(i).x+","+rightSkylinePoints.get(i).y+") ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();


    leftSkylinePoints.addAll(rightSkylinePoints);
    return leftSkylinePoints;
}
```

[These are the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBgDl.png)

As you can see point (6,2) appears to be in the skyline but it shouldn't be because it should have been deleted in the second for loop. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

*For more points I get a lot more that shouldn't be there but for now I want to know about this situation.

**Points are sorted based on their x values (ascending)

Comment: How does your method work? For example, I don't see any comparison of X-coordinates

Comment: I tried to have a go at this and made my own algorithm, but then realized your problem is specifically meant to use the divide and conquer method.  Recursion makes my head hurt.  If you just search "skyline" on stackoverflow there is plenty of help.

Comment: Also your definition of how a point dominates another seems wrong. "A point A(x1,y1) dominates point B(x2,y2) if x1<=x2 && y1<=y2."  That means if two points are identical, then which ever one you consider "point A" dominates the two which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Also you seem to be examining the "horizon," and not the "skyline."

Comment: I forgot to mention that points are sorted based on their x values (ascending order). I have to solve it with a divide and conquer algorithm because I want O(nlogn) complexity. There are no identical points in my input..

Comment: The "method" I 'm using is I find the point with the minimum y value on the left side and I remove every point on the right side with bigger y value than that (points on the left side have smaller x values because they are sorted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've understood logic flaw. It is here:

```
 for (int i=0;i<rightSkylinePoints.size();i++){
       if (rightSkylinePoints.get(i).y>=minY){
           rightSkylinePoints.remove(i);
```

When you remove a point, the rest is shifted left (as far as I understand `remove` sense), so the next (non-treated yet) item gets current index i and is excluded from further treatment.

The simplest solutions - use `while` loop and omit incrementing index if removing occurs.

Another method - loop from larger indexes to lower ones (seems that such direction should not break algorithm)

```
 for (int i=rightSkylinePoints.size() -1; i >=0; i--)
```

Comment: you 're totally right! I forgot about the shifting of the elements when they are removed, thanks a lot!